# More struggles with 3d graphics using the lightweight java gaming library

Tags: java, 3d, window, lwjgl

I am having more trouble with rendering 3d objects in java, heres my new problem I have managed to import the needed libraries (gluPerspective, etc.) however when I run my java application in the eclipse environment, it opens a window, then the window stays black. Here is my code:

```
    package test;

    import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
    import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

    public class Obj3d {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Obj3d obj = new Obj3d();
            obj.start();
        }

        public void start() {
            try {
                Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
                Display.create();
            } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }

            init3dGL();

            while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                clear();
                renderCube();
                Display.update();
            }

            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public void init3dGL() {
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(45, 2, -1, 100);
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
            return;
        }

        public void renderCube() {
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                //front faces
                GL11.glNormal3d(0, 0, 1);
                GL11.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                GL11.glVertex3d(5, 5, -5);
                GL11.glVertex3d(-5, 5, -5);
                GL11.glVertex3d(-5, -5, -5);
                GL11.glVertex3d(5, -5, -5);
            GL11.glEnd();
            return;
        }

        public void clear() {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

    }
```

I can't see my error in the above coding, however I am new to lwjgl 3d programming, so this may be due to my lack of experience. Please be patient, although I am a fast learner. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a negative near distance is not such a good idea, I think. Try

```
GLU.gluPerpective(45, 2, 0.1, 100);
```

And this `2` in there should actually be your window's aspect ratio (width / height), in your case `1.333 = 800 / 600`.

Comment: It still displays a blank screen, with nothing on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. In addition to the answers above, I also didn't clear the screen correctly, and didn't return the method. Careless mistakes.